# "Mesh, Solid or Surface modeling technology" vs. "Mesh, Solid or Surface modeling technologies"

Tags: nouns, grammatical-number

Which of the following should I use?

> - Select between Mesh, Solid or Surface modeling **technology**.
> - Select between Mesh, Solid or Surface modeling **technologies**.

Comment: @corbread ninja-  I think *solid or surface* is a modifier for technology.

Comment: The plural would match best, because there is a list of alternatives. But I'd also like to suggest you would write _choose between_ or _select from_, rather than _select between_ which sounds uneasy to my ear. Given that the use of _technology_ to encompass any slightly new widget is becoming a ridiculous cliche, you might go for _techniques_ instead, or just leave it off and have _models_.

Comment: @Noah, mesh, [solid](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Solid_modeling), and [surface modeling](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Freeform_surface_modelling) are three separate CAD modeling approaches.  Each of those terms modifies the word *modeling*, not *technology*.

Comment: @jwpat7-Sorry, I meant modeling. Don't know about CAD, but the way *solid and surface* were phrased in the orignal question made *them* sound like a single modifier.

Comment: @jwpat7- Your example is much clearer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Neither is quite right, and neither should be used.  Ordinarily, using conjunction *or* causes reference to a single member of the list of three items, rather than providing a plural number of items to choose from.  Instead use either of

- Select Mesh, Solid, or Surface modeling technology.
- Select from among Mesh, Solid, and Surface modeling technologies.

Comment: I like these choices but I would remove "from" in your second choice, so it would read "Select among Mesh..."

Comment: @Tom, according to [ngrams](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=Select+from+among%2Cselect+from+among%2CSelect++among%2Cselect+among&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=0&smoothing=3) for *Select from among,select from among,Select  among,select among*, until ca. 1975 "select from among" was consistently more popular than "select among", but that has reversed in recent years.

Answer (score 0):

Only the second is grammatical. Let's untangle this a little bit.

Suppose you wanted to say something similar about models, which one would you use from the following?

(There is a separate issue because of OP's comma-punctuation convention.  Following examples are edited for pedagogical clarity.)

> Please choose between black and white *model.*
>   Please choose between black and white *models.*

Comment: Noah, I meant to just fix 3 misspellings, but ended up adding a few words to clarify meaning of third paragraph.  Please re-edit if I misunderstood.